# SQL to select random unanswered thing

Tags: mysql

I'm building a survey thing, and have three tables: `users`, `questions`, `answers`, where `answers` contains a record for each question a user has answered (and no record if they haven't answered a given question yet).

My data structure is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )

CREATE TABLE questions (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    text VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )

CREATE TABLE answers (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    id_q INT NOT NULL,
    id_u INT NOT NULL,
    answer VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_q) REFERENCES questions(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_u) REFERENCES users(id)
    )
```

I've tried a few rudimentary things with `LEFT JOIN` and such to no avail. I've used `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1` for the randomness part of the problem. I'm suspecting this isn't as straightforward as I thought. (I'm teaching myself SQL .. would I need to use one of those subquery things I don't know about yet?)

**How do I write the MySQL to select a random question which doesn't have a corresponding answer from a nominated user?**

Comment: Also, please excuse the generic use of "thing" in the question title, because we can't post questions with titles containing the word "question". C'est la vie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with `LEFT JOIN`...

You can use it to make an inverse selection of an `INNER JOIN` with `WHERE column IS NULL`. It's this simple:

```
SELECT    q.*
FROM      questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id_q AND a.id_u = <user id here>
WHERE     a.id IS NULL
ORDER BY  RAND()
LIMIT     1
```

Comment: Ahah, I see what you did - you used the `answers.id_u` specificity to make the join table, and not on the WHERE filter.